# LineChart is not Auto Resize when the dataset is plot in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, linechart

I am using LineChart in JavaFX. I am using Arrays of same length as inputs to plot.
But when i include this in my application the plot is not autosize.
I have included the snapshot how it looks.

[image]

I would like to set the line width smaller and also to change the color.

Here is the code to plot this graph

```
public class ChartPlot extends Application {
    static LineChart<Number, Number> linechart;
    static double[] xArray, yArray;

    public static LineChart linePlot(double[] x, double[] y) {
        xArray = new double[x.length];
        yArray = new double[y.length];

        xArray = x;
        yArray = y;

        // Defining the x axis
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Wavelength");

        // Defining the y axis
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setLabel("Intensity");

        // Creating the line chart
        linechart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

        // Prepare XYChart.Series objects by setting data
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        // series.setName("No of schools in an year");

        // Setting the data to Line chart
        for (int i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(xArray[i], yArray[i]));
        }

        linechart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        linechart.getData().add(series);
        return linechart;
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using the code above to create a LineChart i was unable to reproduce the problem you describe. Could you make a small runnable example which we can run and see the problem?

Comment: I am passing X and Y values from a file... The values are comma seperated. and I have 495 lines in the file, which means length of the array is 495. Please try passing this kind of array to the function.

Comment: I am trying to add linechart on the right side of the splitpane when the user clicks on open button, open should give a file chooser and when i select a file that should be read and plot graph accordingly. I am able to read and separate the values into X and Y values. and plotting. But I have problem with display. I am getting like what the Screenshot I have shared

Comment: I am trying it and still no problem, which is expected cause there is nothing wrong with the code. Could you tell me the Layout of your GUI? I mean what is the Parent of the LineChart? A borderPane, an AnchorPane etc

Comment: I am using AnchorPane

Comment: I thought so. You know that the AnchorPane doesnt really manage the Nodes inside it. Better use a BorderPane and set your chart as a center.

Comment: Ya tried stil the same. I mean chart Layout is setting properly. but the plot inside the chart is not auto-resize. I don't have problem with the layout. I have problem with the plot

Comment: I am using Java 8

Comment: In that case provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example which we can run and test it. You don't need to give us the data too just make a small example. A lot of times in the process of doing so you discover the problem by your own.

Comment: No change.... :( I tried this using JFreeChart it works but not in JavaFX.          Here is the code snippet I have used in JFreeChart                                         chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("","Wave number cm"+'\u2212'+'\u00B9',"Intensity",
     dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true, true, false);
  
   chart.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint( Color.WHITE);
   plot = (XYPlot)chart.getPlot();
   final NumberAxis axis2 = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
   axis2.setAutoRange(true);
   axis2.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xvyqcn276bt4bgw/AABr40ZnHcu94AuQKFSga2Tqa?dl=0.. This is the link for the files which includes this example

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution by my own. :) All I need to do is I have to set the axis the functionality.   here is what I have Corrected.....         xAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
      xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
      yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
      yAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);

Comment: xAxis and yAxis are the NumberAxis for the chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumerAxis need to be added with autoRange. Here is the code

```
public static LineChart linePlot(double[] x,double[] y)
{
    xArray=new double[x.length];
    yArray=new double[y.length];
    
    xArray=x;
    yArray=y;
    
    //Defining the x axis             
  final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(); 
  xAxis.setLabel("Wavelength"); 
    
  //Defining the y axis   
  final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(); 
  yAxis.setLabel("Intensity"); 
    
    //Creating the line chart 
  linechart= new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis); 
     
  
  linechart.getData().clear();
  //Prepare XYChart.Series objects by setting data 
  XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series(); 
  //series.setName("No of schools in an year"); 
        
  //Setting the data to Line chart  
  for(int i = 0; i<xArray.length; i++) 
  {
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(xArray[i], yArray[i]));
  }

  linechart.setCreateSymbols(false);
  
  linechart.getData().add(series); 
   
  //This is what I have Changed
  //---
  xAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
  xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
  yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
  yAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
  //---
  linechart.autosize();
  linechart.applyCss();
    return linechart;
    
  }
      
}
```